# Shorten or split the code

Tags: c

**Please help to shorten this function in order to have 25 or less lines!
it prints all possible combination of numbers from 0 to 99,**

*EX: 00 01, 00 02, 00 03, 00 04, 00 05, ..., 00 99, 01 02, ..., 97 99, 98 99*

```
void    dp_print_comb2(void)
{
    char    a;
    char    b;
    char    c;
    char    d;

    a = '0';
    b = '0';
    while (a <= '9')
    {
        if (b > '9')
        {
            a++;
            b = '0';
        }
        c = a;
        if (b == '9')
            c++; 
        d = b + 1;
        if (b == '9')
            d = '0';
        while (c <= '9')
        {
            ok(a, b, c, d);
            d++;
            if (d > '9')
            {
                c++;
                d = '0';
            }
        }
        b++;
    }
}
```

So if there is a way to split this function or to shorten please help me! thanks!

If the main and other function are needed i can put give them too!

ps: i started to learn C, and making some practice! (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Just superficially, if you really are just trying to reduce lines of code (without simply deleting line feeds): you have two cases where you check `b == '9'` with `d = b + 1` in between. `d = b + 1` isn't impacted by the first check, so you can combine those `if` statements. Also, `d++; if (d > '9')` can be combined as `if (++d > '9')`. `a = '0'; b = '0';` can be written `a = b = '0';`.

Comment: `char a;<ENTER>char b;<ENTER>char c;<ENTER>char d;` can be shortened to `char a, b, c, d;`. Many other constructs in your code can be shortened in a similar fashion by joining lines.

Comment: You can replace `a = '0'; <ENTER> b = '0'; <ENTER> while (a <= '9')` with `for (a = b = '0'; a <= '9'; b++)` and remove the `b++` at the end of your `while` loop block. Again, superficial changes.... By the way, your code doesn't "print" anything. The much shorter approach is to just use a counter (integer) from 0 to 99 and use `printf("%02d\n", n)`. Your function then would be 3 or 4 lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void dp_print_comb2(void){
    for(int ab = 0; ab < 100-1; ++ab)
        for(int cd = ab + 1; cd < 100; ++cd)
            printf("%02d %02d, ", ab, cd);
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: TL;DR.  there isn't a special problem, show that it is possible in a simple loop.

Comment: this problem that select two element from data[n]. first element select index 0..n-1, second element do not choose the ones that have already been selected by first element. It can simply be represented by two loops. So  `for(first_index = 0; ab < n-1; ++first_index)
        for(second_index = first_index + 1; second_index < n; ++second_index)`. BTW In this case the index and content are the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make your code **even** shorter it is possible to make a single loop (Not tested but should work).

```
void foo(){
    for(int i=0,j=0;j<100;i=(i+1)%100,j+=!i)
        printf("%02d %02d,",i,j);
}
```

**How does it work**

- i and j are initialized to 0
- (Loop 0 to 99) Each loop i is incremented. As i!=0 j stay constant (=0)
- (Loop 100) i returns to 0 (n%n -> 0) and j is incremented
- (Loop 100 to 199) Each loop i is incremented. As i!=0 j stay constant (=1)
- And so on...

PS1 : It won't be faster, and it's less clear that using two loops, but it shows a different way to do the same thing.

PS2 : It could be even possible to use only one variable (but it would be even less clear...).

Comment: 1) `int i=0,int j=0` : It can not be compiled. 2) Examples of the OP does not include a combination of overlapping. like (00,00), (99, 99) (and Probably(04, 05) <=> (05,04))

Comment: @BLUEPIXY *`int i=0,int j=0` : It can not be compiled*  It can be compiled with a standard-compliant compiler.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah there was a little inattention error... Edited!

Comment: well, if he don't want 01 <=> 10, he can initialize with j=i+1.

Comment: no, no. pair do not overlap. (first number != second number : (00, 00) is NG if (04, 05) already print, (05, 04) is NG, because It is duplicated as a pair)

Answer (score -1):

from your example, when the numbers are the same, do not print them

Your question was unclear about any other constraints.

This is the code I would use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_PLUS_ONE (100)

// prototype
void    dp_print_comb2( void )

void    dp_print_comb2()
{
    for( unsigned ab=0; ab < MAX_PLUS_ONE; ab++)
    {
        for( unsigned cd=0; cd < MAX_PLUS_ONE; cd++)
        {
            if( ab != cd )
            { // then numbers are not the same
                printf( "%02u %02u, ", ab, cd);
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } // end for
} // end function: db_print_comb2
```

Comment: when downvoting, always include a comment about why you are downvoting.  Other wise, no one learns anything